# Как поставить javascript-цели Яндекс на кнопку отправки формы на странице Контакты Opencart3

Tags: opencart3.x

```html
 <div class="buttons">
   <div class="pull-right">
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ button_submit }}" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'submit', 'submit-contacts-form');
                                                                                       ym(54021358,'reachGoal','submit-contacts-form'); return true;" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Вставляю так в дефолтный шаблон catalog\view\theme\default\template\information\contact.twig - отображения нет. Если создать в своей теме шаблон, перестает работать сама форма, хотя код идентичный дефолтному

Comment: а что в консоли?

Comment: @Kirill уже разобрался. Написал функцию, разместил в главном файле js и подключил в код на событие `onclick`